# How to "write math"

Tags: support, mathjax

I am very new to this site and have asked a few questions but it's become obvious that I have no idea how to "write math" on this site.  I tried some tutorial on here, with /dot and using the brackets and all, but it only made things worse and didn't seem to work when I posted my question.  Can anyone explain to me how to write math on this site.  It's obvious I really have no idea how to start.  Assume you're explaining it to your grandfather/grandmother

Comment: It's really though for someone to give a truly thorough explanations of how to type here. My best advise is to start practicing with simple examples or looking for help in people that edit, eventually you'll get used to it. And also try to read some manuals out there.

Comment: To get started, click on the help drop-down menu at the top, select "Help Center," then click on "[How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)."

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).